# Encrpyting requests on client side

Tags: encryption, frontend, client

Suppose I have a function which makes a POST request to an HTTP endpoint. I want to encrypt the payload on the client side. Suppose my web app has a function `encrypt`. I would like to implement the following workflow:

```
 encrpyt(data) {
     // do some encrpytion
     return encrypted;
 }


 onPost(data) {
     encrypted = encrpyt(data);
     post(encrypted, endpoint);
 }
```

My question is: would it be possible for the client to know the `encrypt` function. I know that over the network the encrpyted data can be seen, but it is possible that there is no way to know the code of the `encrypt` function on the client side. Also, for the app, `data` is not directly implemented by the client but rather it is `data = data(client_input)`.

This question has a generalization which is: if I am using a framework like React/Angular, when I compile my app, are source code functions visible to the client?

Comment: User has full code of your app otherwise it would not work. ***User knows content of ```encrypt``` function***. You could use public encryption to prevent decryption of the data (once it is encrypted) which you send to the server (to prevent user from looking into the data by using development tools ). But User can set breakpoint and examine data before it gets encrypted so you can't hide from User the data which you send to the server.

Comment: What about the case when data is in encrypted on the server and sent to the app function for `decryption`. Regarding the case you described (client encrpyt -> server), how do I open a browser and find this out. Basically I click a button on a form and pass `encrpyt(x) for x in form` to the server with a POST request.